# How to disable Internal Mode of ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I activated the [Internal Mode](https://citizenmatt.github.io/resharper-devguide/Intro/InternalMode.html) of ReSharper (2017.1.3) accidentally by pressing a shortcut key. **How can I disable this mode?** I could not find any entries in the R# options menu or in the GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hit this shortcut | "Yes" button | Restart Visual Studio

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: Thanks - will test it in a few hours - I'm currently at work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Any other tips? I'm using VS 2017.

Comment: Did you have any pop-up appear after you were hitting this key combination? If no, looks like there is no R# key mappings in Visual Studio. So, you need to apply R# keymap scheme first.

Comment: Got the confirmation box and R# restarted afterwards but I had to also restart Visual Studio for the change to take effect. Maybe this was caused by another instance being open, I don't know. It worked though (using VS 2017 15.7.5)